# I moved a VirtualBox VM from a linux machine to Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, arch-linux

I used Copy & Paste to move the entire virtual machine folder, containing the .vdi and .vbox files from my laptop, running Garuda Linux (Arch based) to my Desktop, running Windows 10. But now that I have them all they just look like this:

[image: screenshot of the downloads folder]

With the majority of the snapshots zipped. I can't seem to unzip them properly (I have WinZip). It's not as simple as it is on Linux. I have Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager on my desktop. Could anybody please walk me through opening this VM on my Windows desktop?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have your original VM on your laptop, a better way to move it to a new host is to export it as an OVA.  In Virtualbox, click File | Export Appliance.  That will generate a single .ova file.  Then on your new host, click File | Import Appliance and point it to the OVA file.

Comment: I would also get rid of the snapshots (merge them) if they work anything like VMWare snapshots if a single snapshot becomes corrupt the entire VM is lost.